# What were the circumstances of this impact event on Jupiter in 2012?

Tags: jupiter, impact

I recently came across this video of an impact on Jupiter in 2012:

http://youtu.be/5-msU-YVb9E

Curious about its origin, I did [some research](http://o.canada.com/2012/09/12/what-hit-jupiter-anatomy-of-an-impact/) and found that the video was taken at 11:35 UTC on September 10th, 2012, by amateur astronomer George Hall.  Now that the video had a bit more credence, I became curious as to the circumstances of the event.  The linked article claims the following:

> Currently, the theory is that a 10-metre asteroid hit Jupiter early
>   Monday morning, just below a region known as the Northern Equatorial
>   Belt.

This article was written in September, 2012.  Has anyone else looked into this since that time?  Were any other instruments able to record or document this event? I would like some additional details on what exactly happened, if there are any to be had.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To start off, here's an excerpt from [Wikipedia on this September 2012 Jupiter impact event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Jupiter_impact_event#2012_impact):

> **2012 impact**
>
> On 10 September 2012 at 11:35 UT amateur astronomer Dan Petersen
>   visually detected a fireball on Jupiter that lasted 1 or 2 seconds
>   using a Meade 12″ LX200. George Hall had been recording Jupiter with a
>   webcam on his 12" Meade; upon hearing the news Hall checked the video
>   to see if the impact was captured. Hall had indeed captured a 4-second
>   clip of the impact and released the video to the public. The impact's
>   estimated position in the system was longitude = 345 and latitude =
>   +2. Dr Michael H. Wong estimated that the fireball was created by a meteoroid less than 10 meters in diameter. Several collisions of this
>   size may happen on Jupiter on a yearly basis. The 2012 impact was the
>   6th impact observed on Jupiter, and the fourth impact seen on Jupiter
>   between 2009 and 2012. It was quite similar to the flash observed on
>   20 August 2010.

In a report posted on the [Cloudy Nights forum](http://www.cloudynights.com/ubbthreads/showflat.php/Cat/0/Number/5413921/Main/5413225), Peterson said it wasn't clear if the impact would leave a scar on Jupiter much like those seen in 1994, when the [comet Shoemaker-Levy 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_Shoemaker%E2%80%93Levy_9) broke into pieces and peppered the planet with debris, creating visible impact marks in Jovian cloud tops. It is also not yet known if the object to strike Jupiter was a small asteroid or comet. Peterson wrote:

> *"My best guess is that it was a small undetected comet that is now history, hopefully it will sign its name on Jupiter's cloud tops."*

But, according to [Franck Marchis' Cosmic Diary blog post on the 2012 Jupiter impact event](http://cosmicdiary.org/fmarchis/2012/09/11/some-news-from-the-september-2012-jupiter-flash/), several images were taken before and after the flash by amateurs astronomers around the world, but none were able to detect any debris field visible at the impact site:

[image: September 2012 Jupiter impact event before and afer observations]

<sup>Observations of Jupiter collected before and after the event by amateur astronomers. The arrow indicates the position of the flash.
     No debris field can be seen. Click the image for a higher resolution. (credit: J.H. Rogers, [British Astronomical Association](http://britastro.org/baa/))</sup>

> Despite the large uncertainty on the generated light curve he [Mike Wong]
>   predicted *“that this event is too small to create a visible impact
>   scar“*. The total amount of energy that was derived for this impact is
>   very close to the [June 2010 event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Jupiter_impact_event) one which was analyzed and discussed
>   by R. Hueso and his colleagues in [arXiv:1009.1824](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/2010ApJ...721L.129H).
>
> At the present, since no debris field has been detected and the total
>   energy seems to be low, we can conclude that the flash was most likely
>   a meteor due to a small (diameter <10m assuming a density of 2 g/cc)
>   meteoroid. Even if the event may be 500 times less energetic than
>   recent estimates of the [Tunguska event](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tunguska_event), it is remarkable that an
>   amateur astronomer equipped with a 12″ telescope and a webcam could
>   record it at 730 million of km.

I've included in the quote a link to the [Wikipedia page on 2010 Jupiter impact event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2010_Jupiter_impact_event) that also lists a few other detected Jupiter impacts, but as you might be aware, there were so far 6 impacts observed on Jupiter, among which probably the most famous impact of the 
[comet Shoemaker–Levy 9](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_Shoemaker%E2%80%93Levy_9), in July 1994.

I wasn't able to find any reference that any of the observatories around Jupiter, like maybe the [Cassini-Huygens](http://saturn.jpl.nasa.gov/) detected this impact from 2012.